# Find a 6 month gap and grab everything After it, if there is no 6 month gap then just grab everything

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have added a picture of what I am running into. The ones highlighted are the ones that I need to grab and the ones with the strike-throughs are the ones I don't need. So the first tempid (561346) does not have a 6 month gap so I want all of those row. The second Tempid(661450) has a 6 month gap at row 9 so I just want the next one(row 10) the rest of the rows for that tempid I do not want. 
The Last tempid(662020) has an 8 month gap at line 16 and then there are 4 more rows after it. I want to grab just those 4 rows. I hope this makes sense.

I just need someone to help me. I have been trying to figure this out for days now.

```
  WITH cte AS 
  ( 
  SELECT pt.TempID, MIN(pt.InvoiceDate) AS 'min', MAX(pt.InvoiceDate) AS 
  'Max', 
  pt.JobNumber , 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tempid ORDER BY MAX(pt.InvoiceDate)) AS 
  'Row'  
  FROM #temp t 
  JOIN pamwebhouse..pamtempjobs pt 
  ON SUBSTRING(t.EMPLOYEE, 5,10) = pt.TempID 
  WHERE 
  pt.Status <> 'Posted'
  AND pt.PayTypeID IN ('Regul','OT','Sick') 
  GROUP BY pt.TempID, pt.jobnumber
  ) 
  SELECT a.TempID, a.JobNumber,DATEDIFF(month, a.max, a.start) AS 'Diff' , 
  A.MAX  
  , a.Row  
  INTO #temp2 
  FROM ( 
  SELECT c.TempID, c.JobNumber, c.min AS 'Min', c.max AS 'Max', 
  CASE WHEN c2.TempID IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE c2.min END AS 'Start', c.Row
  FROM cte c
   LEFT JOIN cte c2 
   ON c2.row = c.Row +1
   AND c.TempID = c2.TempID
   --ORDER BY c.TempID
   ) a 

   ORDER BY a.TempID


    --This is what is giving me the output in the screenshot. 
    select t.tempid, t.JobNumber, test AS 'Gap',row,
             max(case when test >= 6 then jobnumber  END) over (PARTITION BY 
    tempid ORDER by max) as id_6
      from #temp2 t
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code or data as images. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Also it is not easy for anybody to help here because there just isn't enough technical detail. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some inspiration.

Comment: Your question is not complete. Please add the details about #temp table with some record examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when gap = 6 then row end) over (partition by tempid order by row) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where (t.gap <> 6 and t.seq is not null);
```

Comment: That did not work. I am currently doing something similar. Thank you though